# Fail to allocate semaphore/netconn Tiva C TM4C1294

Tags: c, memory-leaks, microcontroller, freertos, lwip

I am using tm4c1294+lwip1.4.1+FreeRTOS.

As `netconn_alloc()` is called for `socket communication`, it allocates an unused semaphore. the number of semaphore is defined as SYS_SEM_MAX, so it can not be over `SYS_SEM_MAX`.
However, as semaphores are allocated continuously it reaches `SYS_SEM_MAX` and stop working since I guess `sys_sem_free()` does not deallocate it properly

Here is function that creates a semaphore implemented in sys_arch.c

```
err_t
sys_sem_new(sys_sem_t *sem, u8_t count)
{

  void *temp;
  u32_t i;

  /* Find a semaphore that is not in use. */
  for(i = 0; i < SYS_SEM_MAX; i++) {
    if(sems[i].queue == 0) {
      break;
    }
  }

if(i == SYS_SEM_MAX) {
#if SYS_STATS
    STATS_INC(sys.sem.err);
#endif /* SYS_STATS */
    return ERR_MEM;
  }

  /* Create a single-entry queue to act as a semaphore. */
#if RTOS_FREERTOS
  sem->queue = xQueueCreate(1, sizeof(void *));
  if(sem->queue == NULL) {
#endif /* RTOS_FREERTOS */

#if SYS_STATS
    STATS_INC(sys.sem.err);
#endif /* SYS_STATS */
    return ERR_MEM;
  }



 /* Acquired the semaphore if necessary. */
  if(count == 0) {
    temp = 0;
    xQueueSend(sem->queue, &temp, 0);
  }

 /* Update the semaphore statistics. */
#if SYS_STATS
  STATS_INC(sys.sem.used);
#if LWIP_STATS
  if(lwip_stats.sys.sem.max < lwip_stats.sys.sem.used) {
    lwip_stats.sys.sem.max = lwip_stats.sys.sem.used;
  }
#endif
#endif /* SYS_STATS */

  /* Save the queue handle. */
  sems[i].queue = sem->queue;

  /* Return this semaphore. */
  return (ERR_OK);
}
```

Here is another function that frees semaphore implemented in sys_arch.c

```
void
sys_sem_free(sys_sem_t *sem)
{

  /* Delete Sem , By Jin */
  vQueueDelete(sem->queue);
 /* Clear the queue handle. */
  sem->queue = 0;

  /* Update the semaphore statistics. */
#if SYS_STATS
  STATS_DEC(sys.sem.used);
#endif /* SYS_STATS */

}
```

Whenever `netconn_free()` is called `sys_sem_free()` deallocates the semaphore, but it does not free the semaphore assigned in `sem[] array`.

I added `vQueueDelete(sem->queue);` that was suggested by someone, but still all same.

Not only functions creates/frees `semaphore` but also functions handling `mbox` are same as functions above, so functions handling `mbox` could be wrong as well.

Someone already reported this issue to TI, but it seems they have not solved the problems yet.

Therefore, I may need to implement my own functions handling `semaphore/mbox` in `sys_arch.c`, but I don't have any clues so far.

Can anyone give me any ideas? or anything?

Thanks,
Jin

Answer (score 2):

The sys_arch.txt file in /doc is somewhat helpful. Apparently, looking at that document, and at what lwip 1.3.2 used to do, it looks like the ports/tiva-tm4c129/sys_arch.c is incorrect and incomplete.

sys_sem_free() should indeed be doing the vQueueDelete() as you discovered. It should *not* be doing "sem->queue = 0". If you look at netconn_free() over in src/api/api_msg.c, you can see it calls sys_sem_free() and then sys_sem_set_invalid(). The queue handle will be needed in the second function, and should not be clobbered in the first.

sys_sem_set_invalid() should make a sweep over the sems[] array and if it finds a match to the sem->queue, it should zero out that copy in sems[]. Once that is done, it should set sem->queue to 0.

This, I think, best matches what's in Dunkel's sys_arch.txt document, and fixed the resource leak on my system.

I concur that the mailboxes are in the same shape. Fwiw, I went ahead and modified those in similar fashion to that just described for the sems.

btw, the lwip files I was working with were from the TivaWare_C_Series 2.1.0.12573 third_party folder.